# mysql - scripts report "Too many connections" error, number of connections is < 50

Tags: mysql

I have scripts reporting a "Too many connections" error, but I am monitoring the number of active MySQL connections using pt-stalk and it is not rising above 50. `max_connections` on the server is set to 512.

Does MySQL report such errors under other circumstances?

Comment: check how many files the mysql user may open and if the mysqld reached this limit? (actual files opened, plus unix/tcp sockets open)

Comment: Can you post the exact `pt-stalk` command you're using?

Comment: Exact command: `./pt-stalk --daemonize --dest /var/lib/pt-stalk --collect-tcpdump --variable Threads_connected --threshold 450 --cycles 1 --retention-time 14` (also user and password, which I have redacted)

Comment: Phillip: the open files limit is 2160. How can I check if MySQL has reached this limit?